# ng-repeat not displaying rows

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

Using ng-repeat in angular

I want to iterate through a list and display docName . Tried the below but not getting anything displayed.

```
<div *ngIf = "loggedInUser && !loggedInUser.isAdmin">
            Non Admin
            <div  class="row" *ngIf="faqLi && faqLi.length > 0" style="padding:10px;">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <ul>
                                    <li ng-repeat="faqLi">{{faqLi.docName}}</li>
                            </ul>                            
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Model faq.ts

```
export class Faq {
    id : Number ;
    docName : string = "";
    createDate : Date = null;
    createdByObj : User;
    faqBoards: Board[] ;
}
```

faqLi is a list of faq and it has a length of 4.

```
Im getting this error:
error TS2339: Property 'docName' does not exist on type 'Faq[]'.

    97                                     <li ng-repeat="faqLi">{{faqLi.docName}}</li>
                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I just want to iterate the list and display docName in each row.

I tried `f in faqLi` and `{{f.docName}}` but still getting same

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing `AngularJs` with `Angular`. What you're using is apparently Angular. So `ng-repeat` doesn't exist, instead you can use [ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) :

```
<div *ngIf = "loggedInUser && !loggedInUser.isAdmin">
            Non Admin
            <div  class="row" *ngIf="faqLi && faqLi.length > 0" style="padding:10px;">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <ul>
                                    <li *ngFor="let e of faqLi">{{e.docName}}</li>
                            </ul>                            
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```